# How to integrate wordpress project inside Yii framework?

Tags: wordpress, yii, yii-components

I am doing project in yii framework and I got a part of that project done in wordpress so, i need a way to integrate that project inside Yii project so please help me to do this task.

Comment: http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/?tag=wordpress

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See my article on this subject: http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/322/integrating-wordpress-and-yii-still-another-approach-using-yii-as-the-router-controller/

Comment: Thanks, It work on me can you give me idea about using yii login for both wordpress and yii

Comment: @AnilBhattarai100 Sorry, haven't done that yet, if you do it, would love to get your input on the wiki article or on my Github repo.